# My app crashed due to Dialog box

Tags: java, android, dialog, crash

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder
            (getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault);
    builder.setTitle("Exit").setMessage("Do you really want to Exit ? ")
    .setPositiveButton(" Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

This app crashes when I press the back button.

Comment: Can you post the error log you are getting while crashing?

Comment: What error are you encountering? Post also the logcat here.

Comment: Add error trace or  more information

Comment: can you show error log ??

Comment: Use this instead of getApplicationContext()

Comment: pass context this instead of getApplicationContext().

Comment: You're probably getting a NullPointerException. Post your logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're showing a `Dialog` with the application's context. This is not allowed in Android, as a `Dialog` needs an `Activity` to attach itself to

Change this line

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext(), android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault);
```

Into this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault);
```

As you are using an `Activity` (from the looks of your code), `this` (first parameter) referes to your current activity so this should fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder (this, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault);
```

pass activity reference

Answer (score 0):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder
                (this, R.style.AppTheme);
        builder.setTitle("Exit").setMessage("Do you really want to Exit ? ").setPositiveButton(" Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: The code is already written in Activity Scope so you can directly write `this` instead of `MainActivity.this` :)

Comment: yes of course..in this case we can use this directly.

Answer (score 0):

**First things first.** You cannot show a dialog with Application Context. Dialog needs to be attached to some activity and hence requires Activity context and not Application Context.

You need to override `Activity's` `onBackPressed()` method to handle device's back key event.

You can write like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    confirmBeforeExit();
}

private void confirmBeforeExit() {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Exit")
            .setMessage("Do you really want to Exit ? ")
            .setPositiveButton(" Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }).create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```